# How do I eliminate the phpMyAdmin "Token Mismatch" Error In Safari via MAMP?

Tags: phpmyadmin

After much research and repeated, failed attempts to fix this problem, I am still getting a Token Mismatch error when I try to use phpMyAdmin in Safari accessing a MAMP dev server.  Here's some relevant info:

1. Yes, I've searched for answers online and have tried the various suggested solutions; none have solved the problem
2. I do not get the error in Chrome or any other browser; only Safari
3. I'm sure my tmp directory is set correctly in php.ini
4. I'm sure my tmp directory has been properly flushed before firing up PMA in Safari
5. This problem has persisted across versions of PMA, Safari, PHP, and OSX.  Updating and upgrading has never affected on the bug.  (See versions listed below)

Can anyone from the PMA team tell me definitively how to eliminate this problem?  Is there a config setting to use something other than tokens?

Many thanks in advance,
Steve

System: OSX 10.9.3
Safari: 7.0.4
PMA: 4.2.2
MAMP: 2.2
PHP: 5.3.3

Comment: Hi, you can help us debug this. In libraries/common.inc.php, add some error_log() statements 
    if (PMA_isValid($_REQUEST['token'])) {
        $token_mismatch = ($_SESSION[' PMA_token '] != $_REQUEST['token']);
    error_log('from session');
    error_log(var_export($_SESSION[' PMA_token '], true));
    error_log('from request');
    error_log(var_export($_REQUEST['token'], true));
    }
and have a look at Apache's error log.

Comment: @Marc - Nothing appears in the Apache log.  The only thing that appeared was in the PHP log:  [01-Jun-2014 08:20:21 America/Chicago] NULL
[01-Jun-2014 08:20:21 America/Chicago] from request
[01-Jun-2014 08:20:21 America/Chicago] 'eb53942b4bd1abc2d8feb8fb8543c48f'

Comment: OK, so the value coming from the session for this token is null (in Safari). I'm not sure why. Is your Safari correctly accepting cookies?

Comment: @Marc - I have it set to block "from third parties and advertisers."  Doesn't matter, though.  I tried setting it to never block, and I still get the token mismatch.

Comment: Does the message happen frequently?

Comment: @Marc - it appears 100% of the time

Comment: Sorry, I have no further ideas; I suggest you open a bug ticket at http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/ but you'll notice that we already have a few tickets about Safari problems.

Comment: It's been a while, but FWIW I'm having the same issue on Chrome with MAMP Pro.